# Java Argument to specify Java.Policy file

Tags: java, security, policy

I am trying to load different policy files to security properties file and set an policy file according to the context.

To give little more context, I'm setting different policy files for different users in my system.Therefore I had to first load the policy files in to the security properties file and set the policy file in the run time for current user.

I thought of using System.setProperty() to load the policy files, but then I couldn't set the policy file at run time with the method Policy.setPolicy(). I really don't no where I'm going wrong.  Here's to hoping one of you has the answer!

1. How to set and run a policy file with in a pool of policy files?
2. Can I use `System.setProperty()` to set the policy files and `setPolicy()` to apply it for the run time environment?

Comment: My Question is how to set and run a policy file with in a pool of policy files.Can I use System.setProperty() to set the policy files and setPolicy() to apply it for the run time environment?

Comment: 1) It would have been better to edit the questions into the question!  (I've done that now.) 2) For best results, ask ***1*** question per question, as opposed to 2 or more.

Comment: I got the mistake I made. I would b clear in questioning